# Can a website ONLY have a generic top level domain

Tags: domains, top-level-domains

With the introduction of Generic Top Level Domains that groups can apply for, will it be possible to have a website's host consist of only a top level domain. For example, would it be possible for *example company* to use `http://example/`, after registering "example" as their TLD, instead of `http://example.com/`?

Comment: as far as I know dotless domains are prohibited https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2013-08-30-en

Comment: See also on Stack Overflow: [Why do these URLs without a TLD resolve to a webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26152106/1591669)

Comment: See also [Serverfault: Definition of Fully qualified domain name](https://serverfault.com/questions/609188/definition-of-fully-qualified-domain-name) for more technical details and explanations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From a technical standpoint, it's possible, and there are some examples:

- `http://ai./`
- `http://to./`
- `http://uz./`

These are country code TLDs, but the point is that DNS as a technology does support "dotless" domains.  However, it appears that most generic TLDs are not allowed to have them due to ICANN polices.  According to [RFC 7085](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7085) such restrictions only apply to contracted TLDs, but it's not clear which TLDs fall under that restriction.  [Other sources](https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2013-08-30-en) suggest that the new TLDs would also be subject to such restrictions.

Comment: Browsers don't parse them well either if you just use the domain. Firefox and Chrome think you're searching.

Comment: @Oil These URLs all work for me in Firefox.  Though I will admit that browser settings or plugins may interfere with their correct operation.

Comment: That is crazy...how did they pull off blank domains like that? FYI for those URLs: You have to "paste and go" in Chrome then it will fail, so you click "show details" then view the cached copy to see a recent snapshot.

Comment: Try http://uz./ http://ai./ http://to./ (with periods)

Comment: If I don't include the `.` after the domain name, my system assumes that they are local domains and automatically appends the "search" domain that I have configured.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller did you try doing `http://uz/` or `http://ai/` or `http://to/`? That works for me.

Comment: Thank you @depquid, this answered my question. I guess one alternative if you wanted it to look like a "dotless domain" would be to use `http://www.example/`. How would cookies work if you set them on a dotless domain? Would they be sent to all domains within that dotless TLD?

Answer (score 5):

It is also worth noting that even if you can technically set up a "dotless" domain name (per [depquid](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/24437/depquid)'s answer), it might cost you a pretty penny.

ICANN just [auctioned off the rights to control a bunch of new top level domains](http://mashable.com/2011/06/20/new-gtld-faq/).   The cost of owning a top level domain is $185,000.  In addition to the money, the process also involved technical requirements for being able to operate that TLD, showing that the TLD would be put to good use, a public comment period, and fielding any objections.

Even then [new top level domains may be restricted from operating a dotless domain](https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2013-08-30-en) based on RFC and ICANN rules.